# Extract paths from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I parsed a code and a part of result (AST) is an array like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_ Object
    (
        [flags] => 0 
        [implements] => Array
            (
            )
        [name] => Test
        [stmts] => Array
            (
                [0] => PhpParser\Node\Stmt\ClassMethod Object
                    ( ...
```

Now I want to extract each path of above array. I use below solution:

```
function backKeyPaths($tree){
$paths = array();
foreach ($tree as $key => &$mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        $results = backKeyPaths($mixed);
            foreach ($results as $k => &$v) {
                $paths[] = array($key => $v);
            }
        unset($results);
    } 
    elseif (is_object($mixed)) {
        $results = backKeyPaths($mixed);
            foreach ($results as $k => &$v) {
                $paths[] = array($key => (object) $v);
            }
        unset($results);
    }
    else {
        $paths[] = array($key => $mixed);
    }
}

return $paths;}
```

Actually desired output should be like this:

```
[0] => PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_ Object
(
    [flags] => 0
)
[1] => PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_ Object
(
    [implements] => Array
            (
            )
)
[2] => PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_ Object
(
    [name] => Test
)
[3] => PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_ Object
(
    [stmts] => Array
            (
                [0] => PhpParser\Node\Stmt\ClassMethod Object
                    ( ...
) ...
```

But my solution doesn't return correct class of objects and consider all of them as StdClass objects. Is there any way to cast objects into correct one or extract paths by maintaining the type of values?